# [monaca]How can i change the word of the core plugin to another language?

Tags: monaca

As the Camera Plugin of  Cordova Core Plugins,how can i change the "cancle" to other word,just list "取消"?
I didn't find any location to config this.There is no info at the Monaca Doc. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: For iOS you can try to change "Localizations" in Build Configuration > iOS App. I cannot see any cancel button in Android.